# Summarize count of multiple patterns in shell

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a log file and the following commands

```
grep '"REFERENCE":"78","STATUS":"Buffered"' file.log | wc -l
grep '"REFERENCE":"78","STATUS":"Delivered"' file.log | wc -l
grep '"REFERENCE":"78","STATUS":"Not Delivered"' file.log | wc -l
```

Is there a way using a one liner to get an output like:

```
Buffered: 30
Delivered: 1200
Not Delivered: 589
```

The output has not to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find a solution to my problem, borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587525/61327)

```
grep -oP '"REFERENCE":"79","STATUS":".*?"' file.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Example output:

```
15605 "REFERENCE":"79","STATUS":"Buffered"
24280 "REFERENCE":"79","STATUS":"Delivered"
10224 "REFERENCE":"79","STATUS":"Not Delivered"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of counting lines consider -c switch for grep - it returns number of matches found, and $() or SINGLEQUOTEcommandSINGLEQUOTE syntax in bash, then combine it with bash simple arithmetics $(($X+$Y)) into one command, similarly to:

```
OUTCOUNT=$((`grep -c aaa file1.txt` + `grep -c bbb file2.txt` + `grep -c ccc file3.txt`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to extract the desired lines and output only the status, then use `sort` and `uniq` to obtain the counts for each unique status:

```
awk -F, '/"REFERENCE":"78"/ { print $2 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

This answer may need to be adjusted, depending on the exact format of you input lines. I assume for now that the second field in a comma-delimited line is `"STATUS":"<status>"`.